# Get Integer from XML File and Set to Static Variable?

Tags: java, android, integer

In Android Studio, I have an integer.xml file where I define two integers.  min and max.  If I set min to 8, how do I get this value and set it to a static in Java?

Something like:

```
private static final int MIN = getInteger(R.integer.min);
```

I know this works very differently from getting strings using R.id.string.

No matter what I try, I'm getting errors about static and non-static methods.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize a `final static` variable this way. Final static variable must be initialized at the place of declaration or in `static {}` block, i.e. before any instance of the class has been created.
However, resources are not static. So you can't use `this.getResources().getInteger()` to initialize it: `getResources()` method requires a Context which is not initialized at that time.

One solution is to initialize the variable directly:

```
static final int MIN = 8;
```

Alternatively, you can make it non-`static` and initialize in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

To access getInteger method you need an instance of [resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) first. You generally can do that via [getResources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) method of the Context class (Activity, Service, etc..). So to access a context instance in static declaration, you need to get a static reference to the context, that generally is a bad idea, leading to memory leaks. I would suggest to declare such constants without using resources, just in code. If you have some specific reasons to keep these constants in resources, retain a reference to [application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and use it as intended.